# FPDF borderlines

Tags: php, border, cell, fpdf

I used to make some very simple PDF with this library, FPDF, and now I'm trying to make a "result page" and it have to show something like this image, but with a border surrounding it all, not every cell.

[image: a border must surround all the variables]

I already got that in FPDF, made will Cells (don't know if it's the best way for doing it), and code goes like this (for the moment I added the results by hand, just to figure out how it will look like):

```
//SimpleTable
function SimpleTable() {
    $this->Cell(280,15,"Inscription Number: 1",0);
    $this->Cell(265,15,"Date: 28/03/2008",0);
    $this->Ln();
    $this->Cell(265,15,"Name and Surname: Name Surname ",0);
    $this->Cell(265,15,"",0);
    $this->Ln();
    $this->Cell(280,15,"Address: Address",0);
    $this->Cell(265,15,"",0);
    $this->Ln();
    $this->Cell(280,15,"Zip Code: Zip Code",0);
    $this->Cell(280,15,"City: City",0);
    $this->Ln();
    $this->Cell(280,15,"Year of birth: Birthday",0);
    $this->Cell(280,15,"Age: Age",0);
    $this->Ln();
    $this->Cell(280,15,"VIP: No - First Time: Yes",0);
    $this->Cell(280,15,"School: My school",0);
}
```

Hope you can help me how to border all thouse results in one, I'm not beign able to do it, and didn't find anything.

Thanks again for your time, as always!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Rect(StartX, StartY, Width, Height, Options)
```

Options

- D - Draw Line
- F - Fill
- DF or FD - Draw Line and Fill

Example `$pdf->Rect(0, 0, 210, 100, 'D');`

Answer (score 1):

```
//The BorderBox
$actual_position_y = $pdf->GetY();
$pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(0, 0, 0);
$pdf->Cell($your_content_width, $your_content_heigth, "", 1, 1, 'C');

//Your actual content
$pdf->SetXY($yourLeftosition, $actual_position_y);
$pdf->Cell($cellwidth, $cellheigth, "Inscription Number", 0, 1, 'C');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time, but I finally found the way to make it. On border option from the cell, I added "LT", "RT"... and I could made a border-line that surrounds all (may not the best way to make it, if you know another and better way to make it, I would appreciate that).

Hope this can help other people that wishes to do the same!

Answer (score 0):

Your should first draw an empty Cell with a border surrounding it, then you can store your Y Position and reset the PDF positions and begin to draw your cells within your border Cell.
Like this:

```
//The BorderBox
$actual_position_y = $pdf->GetY();
$pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(0, 0, 0);
$pdf->Cell($your_content_width, $your_content_heigth, "", 1, 1, 'C');

//Your actual content
$pdf->SetXY($yourLeftosition, $actual_position_y);
$pdf->Cell($cellwidth, $cellheigth, "Inscription Number", 0, 1, 'C');
...
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Use FancyRow plugin of fpdf,to give the border or create the box If you need check the link [here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script63.php), it might help you. and the another plugin you can use here is table with multicell, check this [link](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script3.php).

Answer (score 0):

None of the above works.
it can be done with 4th param in cell() method.
4th parameter you can have border as  :

> ```
> L: left
> T: top
> R: right
> B: bottom
> ```

You can provide them in any order with comma separate.
So in your case you can have top row with "L,T,R" as 4th parameter like below:

```
$this->Cell(280,15,"Inscription Number: 1","L,T,R");
$this->Cell(265,15,"Date: 28/03/2008","L,T,R");
```

And for middle part only "L,R" only

```
$this->Cell(265,15,"Name and Surname: Name Surname ","L,R");
$this->Cell(265,15,"","L,R");
```

And bottom one as

```
$this->Cell(280,15,"VIP: No - First Time: Yes","L,R,B");
$this->Cell(280,15,"School: My school","L,R,B");
```